# Converting char to int shows inequal numbers

Tags: c++, type-conversion

I am trying to convert a `char` to `int` for use in a `for` loop, but I am getting what I find unexpected results.

I added a `cout` line to see what value the `char` is getting converted to.

The `char` is taken from an `ifstream` which is streaming from a .txt file that holds letters and numbers. The first number in the file is a 3, but it is being converted into 51.

*code for program is now below*

`is_number(char)` returns true if `char == '0' || char == '1' || char == '2' || ...etc` (up to `char == '9'`)

`in` is an `ifstream`, `out` is an `ofstream`

I have tried casts, such as `int t = (int)inputB` or `int t = static_cast<int>(inputB)` , but they give the same results.

Am I making a rookie mistake? Any ideas?

**edit:**

Minimalised program:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool is_number(char);

int main(){
    ifstream in;
    ofstream out;

    in.open("in.txt");
    if (in.fail()){
        return 0;
    }
    out.open("out.txt");
    if (out.fail()){
        return 0;
    }

    char inputA, inputB;

    while (!in.eof()) {
        if (inputA != 'ÿ' && inputA != '\0') {
            if (is_number(inputB) && inputA != '\\'){

                int t = inputB;   //inputB is 3, but t becomes 51

                cout << inputB << " " << t << ".\n";
                for (int i = 0; i < t; i++){
                    out << inputA ;
                }
            }
        }
        inputA = inputB;
        in.get(inputB);
    }
    return 0;
}

bool is_number(char c){
    if (c == '0' || c == '1' || c == '2' || c == '3' || c == '4' || c == '5' ||
        c == '6' || c == '7' || c == '8' || c == '9') return true;
    return false;
}
```

The contents of the .txt file "in.txt" is:

`zo3logists 10as2ist stewardes2es.3`

(I previously encrypted a line which became that)

Comment: I have a hard time believing that 3 gets converted to 511, unless you're invoking undefined behaviour somewhere.  So can you construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org)?

Comment: Don't do e.g. `while (!in.eof()) ...`, it doesn't work the way you expect it to. The reason being that the `eofbit` flag isn't set until *after* an input operation fails.

Comment: Also, `while (!in.eof())` is always wrong. Use `while (f.good())` instead.

Comment: Is `inputA != 'ÿ'` supposed to test for EOF? If so, better use `if (inputA != EOF ..` then.

Comment: @Jongware It's quite clear that OP is using C++14's inline differential equation solver. The loop runs while the second derivative of `y` is not a constant.

Comment: As said above, please show us a minimal and self-contained test case. Something we can compile and run ourselves, and which only does the bare minimum to reproduce the problem you're seeing

Comment: @H2CO3: That's no better!

Comment: @H2CO3: using `in.good()` works better than `in.eof()` but it may fail to process the last entry in some cases (not the one in this question, though): the problem is that, e.g., an integer right at the end of a file (i.e., without a newline) is read successfully but sets `eofbit'`. As a result `in.good()` becomes `false`. Just use `while (in)` (or, yet better, read the input in the expression, too).

Comment: you are using in.get(inputB) as the last statement of the loop and using inputB before. That's why it's reading the first character wrongly.

Comment: @DietmarKühl Thanks for your suggestion, but I don't see  how that's a problem. When `good()` becomes `false`, the integer has already been read in and the rest of the loop will run anyway.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I have updated to show a slightly larger program.

Comment: Ok, it's clear that you're invoking UB here, which won't be helping things.  For example, on the first iteration, `inputA` and `inputB` haven't been initialized, so have indeterminate values.

Comment: It appears after an edit to cout that 3 is converted to 51, not 511.

Comment: Don't confuse `'3'`, the ASCII character, and `3` the number three. `'3'` the character has a decimal value of 51 (0x33).

Comment: @Mat so how do I convert it into the number 3?

Comment: Remove `'0'`, i.e. `0x30` (48).

Comment: @H2CO3: Surely you are not suggesting to process anything after reading without having checked that the input actually was successful! You always need to check _after_ reading in the first place: Even though `eof()` isn't set, there may be no further characters (e.g., after a `std::getline()` of a file terminated with a `'\n'` you'll have `in.good()` but any attempt to read will fail).

Comment: @DietmarKühl But in this case even `while (f)` is superfluous. Write `while(true)` and throw in a `break` if the reading failed. Right?

Comment: @H2CO3: My main point is this: You always want to test the stream's state when controlling a loop using something like `while (in)`. Using `in.eof()` or `in.good()` will do you not much good: if it doesn't cause a problem, it isn't needed. That is, there is potential cost (it causes a problem) while there is no gain. The preferred approach is to use something akin to `while (in >> value)`, possibly chaining inputs and/or using formatted functions.

Comment: @DietmarKühl I understand that `in.good()` isn't good. But why would you check something *twice?* You check if the reading was successful, then you check it *again?* Why?

Comment: @H2CO3: I wouldn't check things twice! I would check once after reading! I agree that checking against `true` is better than checking `in.good()`. Ideally, I would immediately check the result of the input operation, though.

Comment: @DietmarKühl Yes yes, that's what I'm saying too. (I was confused by your "check the state of the stream" phrase, whereas you really meant to check the state of the input operation.) Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int t = inputB;
```

This is not the right way to do the conversion. This way you get a [character code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), and this is not what you want.

Use this:

```
int t = inputB - '0';
```

You can also write this as `int t = inputB - 48`, which is exactly the same (if your system uses ASCII encoding - almost universally true), but the version with the `'0'` is considered more readable (and correct regardless of character encoding).

Answer (score 1):

First, your `inputA` and `inputB` are undefined at the beginning of the loop. The solution from anatolyg is the simplest. You could also use something like this:

```
// include <string>

string str;
sstr = inputB;
int t = stoi(str); // you have to be sure that inputB is a number
                   // or need exception handling
```

You would be safe, when the charset would be ever changed that '1' comes not after '0'. But this is pretty unsure ;)

Btw: you could simplify your `ìs_number(char c)`:

```
if ('0' >= c && c <= '9')
    return true
else
    return false
```

Comment: .. actually, `return '0' >= c && c <= '9';` is even more simple. Or `return isdigit(c);` -- wait, looks like you don't even have to write a function!